# Python subtext comparsion with a list

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I don't have the full code yet, i'm stuck at the concept level of my project.

I'm automating some stuff with selenium chromedriver.

Partial code:

```
ws_number = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="adatok_table"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]').get_attribute("textContent")
warr_type = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="adatok_table"]/tbody/tr[16]/td[2]').get_attribute("textContent")
device_type = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="adatok_table"]/tbody/tr[8]/td[2]').get_attribute("textContent")
partner = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="adatok_table"]/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]').get_attribute("textContent")
```

I'm stuck where i get the text content of device_type, because it has junk info in it. And i need to strip it down.

The junk looks like this : (Samsung SM-G930F Fekete - BLACK )
What i need from this is (G930).

How can i narrow it down easily?
And how can i compare that with a list?

Comment: did you try using `regex`?

Comment: You'll have to explain how exactly you get "G930" from "Samsung SM-G930F Fekete - BLACK". At the moment, with the little information you gave us, `"Samsung SM-G930F Fekete - BLACK"[11:15]` would be a valid solution to your problem.

Comment: The whole text element looks like this : Samsung SM-G930F Fekete - BLACK, what i need from this is just (G930).
I can't do [11:15] because this string is stored in a value called device_type.
And it's going to be different each and every time i open my worksheet here at work.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how varied the junk is you could use regex to clean up the content.

```
import re

dirty = "Samsung SM-G930F Fekete - BLACK"
regex = "^.+-([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}).+$"

m = re.search(regex, dirty)

print(m.group(1))
```

Something like that would give you your "G930".

Comment: Can you explan how this works? because i have to implement it to like 30 different device types. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, I use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to test it for me. 

The `^.+-` basically says to match anything from the start of the string until you reach "-".

The `[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}` says to match 1 uppercase character followed by 3 digits and the `.+$` says to match anything until the end of the string. 
`(...)`  contains our capture group, that is where we attempt to match what we want to return.
The first group item is the original string. 
That is why when we call m.group(1) we get G930. If you were to call m.group(0) you would get Samsung SM-G930F Fekete - BLACK.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this into a loop or something?

Because otherwise i'd have to make this for each device-type which is not so ideal :/

Comment: Definitely, do you have the list of device types you wish to use?

That regex was tailored quite specifically to that string you provided.

Comment: Yeah i've done the list by myself :)

this is the one:


types = ["A320","A520","B550H","B2710","G388","G389","G390","G800","G870","G900","G901","G903","G930",
         "G935","G950","G955","I9295","N950","R360","R365","R600","R720","R732","R760","R770","S7710"]

Comment: Try `([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3,4})` as your regex string.

Comment: maybe i'm a noob but i'm getting this error when i'm doint it live.

error:


AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

My code is:

m = re.search(regex, device_type)
print (m.group(1))

device_type is getting a string automatically from a website.

Comment: Okay, so that is saying that `m` after the regex search is a NoneType. That most likely is a result of the regex failing to find anything. You could just add 
m = re.search(regex,  device_type)

if m is None:
    print ("ERROR:" + device_type)
else:
    print(m.group(1))
``

Comment: Have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/lutzenburg/490048eeee5035953c8ea04b3d7887b9)

Comment: got it! your idea is worked as a debugging method, the XPATh was wrong and was pointing to another location, on the site, now i'm getting the result. now i have to implement it in a loop or something. But that's another topic

thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Try `find_elements` in place of `find_element` to find multiple matching xpaths objects. That should give you a list of sorts to loop through.